# Classification of singularities - Pole

Tags: complex-analysis, laurent-series, singularity

**Definitions of a pole :**

1. The isolated singularity $z_0$ is a pole, of order $k$ $\iff$ $a_{−k}≠0$ and $a_n=0$ for all $n<−k$.
2. $f$ has a pole of order $m$ at $z_0$ if there exists a function $g$ that is holomorphic in a neighbourhood of $z_0$ such that
   $ (z-z_0)^m f(z) = g(z) $ with $g(z_0) \not= 0$

Is anyone could explain to me in details why both definition are equivalent?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your definition (2) is incorrect. It must also include $g(z_0) \neq 0$. Let $f$ be a complex function with pole of order $m$ at $0$. Let $\sum_{j=-\infty}^\infty a_j z^j$ be its Laurent series expansion at $0$ **with inner radius** $0$. I made the centre of the power series to be $0$ for convenience.

Definition (1) $\implies$ Definition (2): If Definition (1) holds with order $m$, we have
$$ f(z) = \sum_{j=-\infty}^\infty a_j z^j = \sum_{j=-m}^\infty a_j z^j
$$
We can define $g(z) = \sum_{j=0}^\infty a_{j-m} z^j$. Evidently $z^m f(z) = g(z)$, and since $g(z)$ is a power series, it is holomorphic within its radius of convergence, which is not zero since the outer radius of $f$ is not zero.

Definition (2) $\implies$ Definition (1): Let $g(z) = \sum_{j=0}^\infty a_j z^j$. Then
$$ f(z) = \frac{1}{z^m} g(z) = \sum_{j=-m}^\infty a_{j+m} z^j
$$
 Since $g(0) \neq 0$, we have $a_0 \neq 0$, and all terms below $j = -m$ are zero.